# Service unavailable issue only from Mac

Tags: java, macos, soap

I am trying to access a SOAP web service . I keep getting this error

> java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable".

I tried all possible solutions, also added another `Authenticator` class. The same works in Windows without any additional classes. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Can you post code?

Comment: I am using TransformerFactory and SOAPConnectionFactory. Sorry I cannot paste the entire code. This pretty much explains it all.I do doTrustToCertificates();SOAPConnectionFactory scf = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance(); connection = scf.createConnection();SOAPMessage soapResponse = connection.call(requestMessage, url);
 Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
return soapResponse.getSOAPPart();